# P-value (statistics) T-test Analysis of Variance (statistics) +2 What does p-value of 0.7624 mean in a t test with two groups of relevation?

Tags: r, anova, variance, t-test, p-value

I’ve done 2 testing on 40 users using 2 Mobile App for each one
I’ve got the time that each user has spent on them
T-Test’s result is:
t=0.48448,df=76.638,p-value=0.6294
Hyp-Alt: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95% confidence interval:
 -5.443252 8.943252
mean(a):13.95 mean(b): 12.20

Answer (score 0):

The test is telling you that there is no statistical difference between the means of the 2 tests that you gave each user. Given your data you might want to try a paired t-test (if you haven't already)